# How do I compile a JUnit test with Maven that uses the Java Compiler API?

Tags: maven, junit, classpath, javac

Running the Java Compiler from a JUnit test is pretty simple using the [Java Compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). The test checks that I can load new code using a temporary classloader and that the cleanup works, etc

My problem is compiling and/or running the test using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

If I add the java compiler using a dependency, I must set the scope to `test`. If I do that, the `tools.jar` will be added to the classpath when the tests are being compiled which means that there will be **two** Java compilers on the classpath.

The same is true for the scope `runtime` but that will also add the Java compiler to my artifact, making it leak. All other scopes are even worse.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use fork mode always so that the leak isn't a problem.

Comment: There are still two java compilers in the classpath of the newly created process.

Comment: I'm wary what happens when I compile with Java 7 and the tools.jar comes from Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you need the java compiler dependency at all? Without any special (compiler) dependency the Java Compiler API works for me (as it's part of the JDK).

You can set the target VM version with the [`options`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) parameter of `getTask`, for example:

```
final List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("-target");
options.add("1.3");
options.add("-source");
options.add("1.3");
```

Comment: Taking into account that Maven doesn't work with a JRE, you're right, of course. Silly me.